# Cannot make new project in QT on mac osx

Tags: macos, qt, qmake

I have been stuck on this for the past couple days. I have installed QT 4.8 and I have installed the libraries as well. But when I come to make a new project, I am only given the option of creating a plain C++ project with CMake. I do not have the option of using the automated qmake. And I have no idea why. If someone could please help it out it would be much appreciated.

Here is a picture of what I see.

[image]

When I see the kits in preferences, I see this.

[image]

But in the QT versions section, If I click on that to choose something, It is empty. There is nothing to choose from.

Comment: I don't have creator on this computer, but there should be a settings section where you point it at your Qt installation. Have you checked that?

Comment: Have you setup any kits?

Comment: I havent setup any kits. Everytime i come to do that it doesnt work for some reason.

Comment: Go to 'Qt Versions' and add path to 'qmake'. After that you will be able to set 'Qt version' in your kit.

Comment: When I try to add the path to QT version, I cant because I cant access the /usr/bin folder from the popup window that asks me to choose the executable file to add. do you know how I can get around that

Comment: That is very strange. Try typing `ls -l /usr`. Access rights to your bin directory shold be: `drwxr-xr-x`. If they are not - type `sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin`.

Up: all above is true for linux. As I can see, you are using macos. I am not familar with it. Basically, what you need to do, is to give yourself access rights to read and execute from `/usr/bin`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. **Add a Qt Version.**  Go to Qt Creator > Preferences... > Build & Run > Qt Versions.

   - Click Add.
   - **On Mac, `/usr` is hidden by default, but you can access the path directly — press <kbd>⌘⇧G</kbd> and type `/usr` into the popup.**
   - Navigate to your `qmake` executable and click Open.
   - Under Helpers, expand Details, and click Build All.
2. **Add a Qt Kit.**  Go to Qt Creator > Preferences... > Build & Run > Kits.

   - Click Add.
   - Select your compiler and Qt version.
   - Click OK.
3. **Make sure the qmake-related plugins are enabled.**  Go to Qt Creator > About Plugins... and enable the following:

   - Build Systems > GenericProjectManager
   - Build Systems > Qt4ProjectManager
   - Build Systems > QtSupport
   - Qt Creator > ProjectExplorer
   - Qt Quick > QmlJSTools — **As of Qt Creator 2.7.0, qmake projects now need QmlJSTools, which might not be enabled if you had a previous version of Qt Creator installed.**
   - Then, click Close and restart Qt Creator.  You should now be able to create qmake projects.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH. That did it for me. I appreciate the detailed explanation of this solution. Thanks again.