# Adding a Homebrew-installed Qt to Qt Creator on a Mac

Tags: macos, qt, homebrew, qt-creator, hidden-files

I installed Qt5 and Qt Creator via [homebrew](https://brew.sh/). Since they were installed independently of each other, Qt wasn't automatically added to the list of known Qt installations in Qt Creator. I thought adding an installation would be simple, but...

Since homebrew installs all casks under `/usr/local/`, which is a hidden directory, I can't navigate to the desired Qt installation using the folder navigation dialog opened by Qt Creator, when `Kits > Qt versions > add` is pressed in the options. I have used the terminal to make hidden folders and files visible in the "normal" Finder, but they don't show up in Qt Creator.

How do I add a Qt installation located in a hidden folder to Qt Creator?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713682/cannot-make-new-project-in-qt-on-mac-osx

Answer (score 5):

It's weird but even if I can see hidden files and folders on my Mac, **usr** folder don't appear in the search window of Qt when I want to add a new Qt version.

To reach it out you can use ⌘⇧G yes, and, **if your Qt version is 5.12.1** the full path to copy paste would be something like that:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.12.1/bin/qmake
```

Or you can create a shortcut for usr folder if you want, control click on the **usr** folder and click on "Create an alias" that would be visible in the search window of Qt, or in the terminal use **ln -s** to create a symlink in the folder where you want to find the symlink.

```
ln -s /usr/
```

or

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.12.1/bin/
```

Then it's easy to select the **qmake** file to add a new Qt version to Qt-creator.

After that if you have a problem with **GCC** and **G++**, to make it work properly you need to select **Clang** in the kit settings.

Comment: Note newer versions of homebrew have their Cellar in `/opt/homebrew/Cellar`

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r I think that's in Linux, right? Unless brand new installations of homebrew use `/opt/homebrew/Cellar` as well... while 'old' installations with 'new' versions of homebrew continue to use `/usr/local/Cellar`.

Answer (score 1):

"On Mac, /usr is hidden by default, but you can access the path directly — press ⌘⇧G and type /usr into the popup."

Answer (score 0):

As-of https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/124923 being merged today: you can add Homebrew's Qt to QtCreator's "Qt Versions" in:

```
Preferences > Qt Versions > Link with Qt...
```

pressing "`Choose...`" and selecting as the Qt installation path the location of your `$(brew --prefix)` i.e. `/opt/homebrew` on Apple Silicon or `/usr/local` on Intel. As mentioned elsewhere (thanks!), you may find ⌘⇧G helpful in selecting the full path here.