# Adding a Homebrew-installed Qt to Qt Creator on a Mac / Missing Examples and more

Tags: qt, installation, version, homebrew

My problem is not quite the same as the previous post with a somewhat similar name from a few years ago. I apologize if that confuses anyone.

[Adding a Homebrew-installed Qt to Qt Creator on a Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53683242/adding-a-homebrew-installed-qt-to-qt-creator-on-a-mac)

I just upgraded to Big Sur on my iMac and have found that my old installs of Qt5 won't work because of the changes Apple made to the operating system, etc. So, I finally decided to use the Qt version I had already installed with homebrew but never had an opportunity to try.

I've tried to follow the instructions at [Qt directions on adding versions from other package managers](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake.html) https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake.html for Setting up a new Qt version. I never was able to do their step #3
"Select the Qt version to view and edit it" because I could never find that in the preferences dialog.preferences dialog:
[image: preferences dialog]

Everything else on that dialog seems right. But, I'm confused as what else I need to do to get this to work.

I can't figure out how to set up a kit (under the kit tab) or whether I need one.

I don't see any of the traditional Qt examples. I wanted to test the install with a couple of them. I do see this message about linking to a Qt installation, but I don't know if this applies to the homebrew stuff or not.

message about linking:
[image: message about linking]

How to ensure that I have everything I need in terms of version and kits and "seeing" the Qt examples.

Comment: I followed the suggestion @ https://travis-ci.community/t/installing-qt-qmake-via-brew/10389 but am still at the same place.  Can anyone help with this?

Comment: I followed the suggestion @ https://travis-ci.community/t/installing-qt-qmake-via-brew/10389 but am still at the same place.  It's possible that the given advice is fine.  Problem might be related to this error that I can't for some reason upload as a figure: Failed opening project "/Applications/Qt/Creator.app": No plugin can open project type "inode/directory".

Answer (score 0):

Okay.  I can't really marked this as solved.  I had to install Qt5 from the "standard" Qt on-line installer.  The only thing that I can conclude is that the "Brew" people missed something on their end with the port.

Answer (score 0):

As-of https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/124923 being merged today: you can add Homebrew's Qt to QtCreator's "Qt Versions" in:

```
Preferences > Qt Versions > Link with Qt...
```

pressing "`Choose...`" and selecting as the Qt installation path the location of your `$(brew --prefix)` i.e. `/opt/homebrew` on Apple Silicon or `/usr/local` on Intel. You may find ⌘⇧G helpful in selecting the full path here.