# Problem with QT Creator when installing bundles via homebrew

Tags: qt

I installed qt and qt-reator via homebrew. since they were installed via homebrew. Qt was not automatically added to the known qt settings lists in qt-reator. I thought adding the installation would be easier.
But then, I installed or uninstalled something, and Qt Creator stopped collecting data through qmake.
The issue is resolved with the problem in Russian form
I did everything that was said here, but still nothing worked as expected.
I have already reinstalled Qt 4 times. Tried different versions. The result is always negative.
[Adding a Homebrew-installed Qt to Qt Creator on a Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53683242/adding-a-homebrew-installed-qt-to-qt-creator-on-a-mac)

I don’t know what else to do to make everything work as it should. On a work machine, on Linux, everything is fine, but there everything is a completely different approach. But I can’t figure out this problem with makeup.

How to add my qmake to Qt forums?
Here are my screenshots.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJ8Ek.png)

```
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMQeB.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUtJC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksyCs.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0At8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTToH.png)
```